# angular resource created http in https

Tags: angularjs, resources, angular-resource

I am writing angular resources for url as

```
factory('DataRow', ['$resource', function($resource){

    return $resource('/:module/rows/:id', null,

        {
            query: {isArray: false},
        }
    );
}]).


DataRow.query(params,
   function(data){ $scope.data = data.results;
      $scope.count = data.count;
      $scope.headers = [];
      if ($scope.module == 'result' && data.results.length > 0){
        var headers_obj = JSON.parse(data.results[0].items);
           for (var i in headers_obj){
               $scope.headers.push(i);
           }
        }
   },
```

I am using this code in the server https://example.com all others resources work fine but while using this resource it requests to http://example.com as a root url ? How this resource creates a complete url ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I miss one '/' at my url.

factory('DataRow', ['$resource', function($resource){

```
return $resource('/:module/rows/:id/', null,

    {
        query: {isArray: false},
    }
);
```

}]).

works fine.